# MySQL calculating age based on birthDate

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am trying to `calculate the age` based on the birthDate in MySQL using SQL statement.

My birthDate was varchar() and in this format: 29/11/1994 (DD/MM/YYYY).

My SQL statement:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(YY, birthDate, GetDate()) AS Age
FROM bookedevent be INNER JOIN account a
ON be.bookedEventBY = a.accountName WHERE a.accountID = 1
```

However, when I test in MySQL workbench, I am getting this error message: Incorrect parameter count in the call DATEDIFF.

ANy guides?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use date(GetDate())-instead

Comment: Are you missing the `birthDate`'s object? Incorrect `INNER JOIN` since you missed to specify where the `birthDate` belongs to. Either be.`birthDate` or a.`birthDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using SQL Server syntax in MySQL.  That won't work.  You can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthDate, CURDATE()) AS Age
FROM bookedevent be INNER JOIN
     account a
     ON be.bookedEventBY = a.accountName
WHERE a.accountID = 1;
```

Note that the semantics for `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` are different than for `DATEDIFF()` in SQL Server.  However, `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` is probably closer to what you really want.

Comment: I am getting null when I test the SQL. Is it because the my birthDate column is varchar()?

Comment: Probably.  You should store dates as dates, not strings.

Comment: Is there anyway to convert the string to date? Because I cannot change the data strcuture of that table as my friend is using it as well

Comment: Nevermind I got it already. You can do in this way: str_to_date(e.eventDate,'%d/%m/%Y'). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any ways to group the age like 1-10 as one group. then 11-20 as another group using SQL statement?

Comment: Yes, you would use a `case` statement to define the ranges, and then group by the variable (or the `case` statement).

Comment: Sorry I am confused. Would you mind to provide me some examples?

Comment: You should probably ask another question with more detail about how you want things groups.  Asking questions in comments is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(birthDate, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(birthDate, '00-%m-%d')) AS age
FROM bookedevent be INNER JOIN
     account a
     ON be.bookedEventBY = a.accountName
WHERE a.accountID = 1;
```